# While trying to insert nosql document into IBM Db2 z/os, getting DSN5JSJb module is not found. But it's there already in environment?

Tags: json, db2, mainframe, db2-zos, nosql

While inserting json document in to table facing the mentioned error.  Though I created UDF where external name is DSN5JSJb and it's already there in environment. Which will come along with Db2 accessories​ suit.

Comment: did you following the config steps?: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1501sql-json-db2/index.html

Comment: based on that error it is definitely something with your config

Comment: We followed everything appropriately,  but getting sql code - 444. Here json api intended to use. So jdbc driver also there.

Comment: you will probably have to talk to the technical staff at your site, the SQL code -444 enforces your question title DSN5JSjb is not found. If you are sure that everything is configured properly, my next question would be is this running in Batch or Online, and if it is running Online, does CICS have access to this module?

Comment: Are you sure the module name is in mixed case: `DSN5JSJb`?

Comment: yea, module name is in mixed case only @mustaccio

Comment: i trying to to insert nosql document into table by creating UDF functions, it's via spufiin in db2 . just trying to find whether it's inserting , and able to retrieve it back . @SaggingRufus

Comment: you are going to have to talk to someone who understands the configuration of this product and the configuration of your site. At this point we are all just guessing. The system usually isn't wrong, so I am thinking the configuration was not done properly.

Comment: Well, `DSN5JSJB` being a system module, I doubt it was created in mixed case in your subsystem, while the rest of the world enjoys all uppercase name. I suggest you try using the uppercase name too in you UDF.

Comment: @SaggingRufus now it's working , technical side they failed to add the module in db2 proc library

Comment: The system is usually correct